# Reorder HTML List with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, reorderlist

I'm seeking help to see if it's possible to reorder the items in a navigation bar. The bar itself is created by a module within a CMS that is locked to editing.

As such, I'd like to reorder the "buttons" so that the 4th option will move to be the 1st in the menu bar.

The locked module creates the following HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-primary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/1" class="nav-link">AAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="/2" class="nav-link">BBB</a></li>
        <li><a href="/3" class="nav-link">CCC</a></li>
        <li><a href="/4" class="nav-link trigger">DDD</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Could I accomplish this with Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: "*Could I accomplish this with Javascript or jQuery?*" - yes. Yes, you could. But where did you get stuck trying to implement this yourself?

Comment: get last li and prepend it to the ul

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get the list items, and a reference to the `ul`. Then prepend the last list item to the `ul`:

```js
var listItems =  document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-primary li');

document.querySelector('.navigation-primary > ul').prepend(listItems[listItems.length - 1]);
```

```html
<div class="navigation-primary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/1" class="nav-link">AAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="/2" class="nav-link">BBB</a></li>
        <li><a href="/3" class="nav-link">CCC</a></li>
        <li><a href="/4" class="nav-link trigger">DDD</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you... you kindly helped a designer comfortable with HTML and CSS that is relatively clueless with javascript.